# Not getting number in SMS and proper number in Phone call but in emulator

Tags: android

I have tried tel: and sms: in WebView. After click if i get URL containg tel: then i am opening call utility of phone. Then i am getting number followed by character 'N'. An in sms: i am getting sms utility of phone but no number. In both URL number is present.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    result = false;
    // for telephone
    if (url.contains("tel:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        result = true;
    }



    // for SMS or message.
    if (url.contains("sms:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        result = true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, url);
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Call utility, use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` in place of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`
and
For SMS Utility, use "smsto:" prototype in place of "sms:" and also use `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` in place of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`